# Spring boot, does not create beans @Controller, @Service

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is my project directory structure.

[image]

All controller and other classes and directories, which are beans, are under the "WebPortalApplication" class, and as Spring Boot doc states, we do not explicitly specify the package to scan for beans, whenever those packages locate unther the "main" class directory, right?
So when I run the "WebPortalApplication" file, it builds, but with such exceptions.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; 

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'roleRepository'; 

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.epam.webPortal.model.Role
```

@RestController
public class UserRestController {

```
@Autowired
UserService userService;
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserRestController.class);

//-------------------Retrieve All Users--------------------------------------------------------
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listAllUsers() {
    String userAsJson = "";
    List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
    try {
        userAsJson = JsonConvertor.toJson(users);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Something went wrong during converting json format");
    }
    LOGGER.info("displaying all users in json format");
    return userAsJson;

}

 package com.epam.webPortal.service.user;

import com.epam.webPortal.model.User;
import com.epam.webPortal.repository.role.RoleRepository;
import com.epam.webPortal.repository.user.UserRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

@Service("userService")
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findAll()));
        user.setDateRegistered(new Date());
        userRepository.save(user);
        LOGGER.info("user with username {} successfully saved", user.getUsername());
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAllUsers();
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(Long Id) {
        return userRepository.findById(Id);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        final User entity = userRepository.findById(user.getId());
        if (entity != null) {
            entity.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
            entity.setLastName(user.getLastName());
            entity.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            entity.setSkypeID(user.getSkypeID());
            entity.setDateRegistered(new Date());
            entity.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
            userRepository.save(entity);
            LOGGER.info("user with id {} successfully updated", user.getId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUserById(Long id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
        LOGGER.info("user with id {} successfully deleted", id);
    }
}

package com.epam.webPortal.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<User> users;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

Comment: the image does not help. Post a reduced version of your classes.

Comment: Paste the "relevant" code (definition and constructors) for: `UserRestController`, `UserService` and `Role`...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using JPA.
All JPA entities must be annotated with @Entity.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.epam.webPortal.model.Role
```

means, Role class is missing @Entity annotation.

Comment: Yes, they are annotated

Comment: Role class also

Answer (score 0):

I expect below definition on your RoleRepository; sharing this file will help to further analyze on what is missing.

```
public interface RoleRepository implements CrudRepository<Role, Long> {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled your repos?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class WebPortalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebPortalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```